# Shell script file with multiple commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, maven, batch-file

I want to make shell script file in windows and linux with multiple commands inside it.

E.g run.sh and run.bat with the below commands 
**run.bat** or `run.sh`

```
mvn clean
mvn install
mvn exec:java
```

When I run my `run.bat` file it only executes first command `mvn clean` but it do not execute other commands.

**How to make shell-script file with multiple commands so that when I execute it, It executes all commands inside it.**

Thanks.

Comment: Check your output (I know maven is verbose and doesn't help), you must have an error coming from the .bat file somewhere. It should be executing the 3 commands sequentially.

Comment: Well, the first command *could* be raising some sort of error as Aaron suggests, but since your script isn't error-checking that shouldn't matter.  There's something omitted here, because if you're at a Windows cmd prompt and you run a .bat file it will run all the commands.  But, btw, this isn't a case where you need that; you can list multiple goals on a single `mvn` command line

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I was thinking about a .bat syntax error. Now that I think a little more about it, I wouldn't be surprised if missing `\r` linefeeds would make `cmd` understand the whole `.bat` as a single line, so I would check for that

Comment: Also OP, unless you're still running XP, you could chose powershell's `.ps` scripts as an alternative to `.bat` scripts ; their syntax is much closer to `.sh` files (although they still are two vastly different environnements). I feel like they're still not used a lot in the industry, but if you need some kind of guarantee RedHat started including `.ps` scripts in their JBoss EAP 7.0 release (although they still include equivalent `.bat`)

Comment: @Aaron it only executing first command `mvn clean`

Comment: @PrakashPandey have you checked npocmaka's answer? It is likely the solution to your problem. If it is, I still recommend you consider using `powershell` instead of `cmd`, I think the problem wouldn't have happened then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mvn` is bat file but not binary.

Try with

```
call mvn clean
call mvn install
call mvn exec:java
```

Comment: wow... I completely forgot that .bat scripts don't, by default, return to other .bat scripts.  Holy 80's batman.  Nice catch.

Comment: @PrakashPandey - with `.sh` files you should not have the same problem

Comment: yes, it also worked. doing `chmod 777` worked. Big thanks

Comment: If it is a Windoze Batch Script, why is this post then tagged with *bash* and *linux*??????

Comment: Oops! You seriously want to write a program which is valid as a bash program AND a Windows Batch program at the same time??? This is weird.   It will work only in the simplest cases. Even the solution by npocmaka, which you had accepted, would work as a bash script only, if you define a separate program named *call*. As soon as some additional logic (conditionals, status code evaluation,...) is added, it will become a nightmare. I suggest to stick to a single language, which is available on both Linux and Windows. If you want to run bash, you can do it on Windows too.